# Dynamically assign z-index in ascending/descending order to unknown number of elements with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout

I have an element with class `.book` which contain random number of elements with class `.page`.

```
<div class='book'>
    <div class='page'></div>
    <div class='page'></div>
    <div class='page'></div>
    <div class='page'></div>
    <div class='page'></div>
</div>
```

The `.pages`s are laid out on top of each other like pages in a book so the first `.page` element needs to have the highest z-index which is equal to the number of `.page` elements in `.book`.

Currently I manually assign each `.page`'s z-index in the CSS, but I'd like more flexibility.
Is there a way to count the number of `.page` elements in `.book` and dynamically assign `z-index` appropriately using javascript? I'd also like the inverse to happen. When a `.page` is flipped I'd like the z-index order assigned to it in reverse order.

Example:
Normal:

```
<div class='book'>
    <div class='page' style='z-index: 5'></div>
    <div class='page' style='z-index: 4'></div>
    <div class='page' style='z-index: 3'></div>
    <div class='page' style='z-index: 2'></div>
    <div class='page' style='z-index: 1'></div>
</div>
```

First three `.page`s flipped:

```
<div class='book'>
    <div class='page flipped' style='z-index: 1'></div>
    <div class='page flipped' style='z-index: 2'></div>
    <div class='page flipped' style='z-index: 3'></div>
    <div class='page' style='z-index: 2'></div>
    <div class='page' style='z-index: 1'></div>
</div>
```

I'm okay with jQuery.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L8E8a/)

**UPDATE**:
Everyone's answers works as intended on the reduced test case but when I used it on the original work, the 'z-index' order didn't seem to update.
 **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/HwR9c/ (sans your code).
I'm using jQuery to toggle `.flipped` class on the '.page' element when it's clicked:

```
$('.page').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Here's where I'm applying this to, please feel free to use them:
[Responsive Book Layout](http://codepen.io/carpenumidium/pen/dBpeo)
[Book](http://codepen.io/carpenumidium/pen/EoxGg)

Comment: I see you are enjoying answers with fewer lines.  As it was clear that you were not a javascript pro, it seemed appropriate to provide an answer that was clearer / easier to follow.  If brevity is required, then it can be done, but it becomes less clear to someone reading the code what is going on.

Comment: Will revise answer based on your update soon

Comment: @cale_b just letting you know that juvian posted an update which works great http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/HwR9c/8/ but i'll wait if you have a better answer :). thanks for your help nonetheless!!!

Comment: I've modified my answer (added to it at the end).  It's tested in your fiddle and works properly (note that you need to replace / alter your `$('.page').click()` per my revised answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works:

```
$(".book").each(function(){
    var pages=$(this).find(".page")
    var pages_flipped=$(this).find(".flipped")
    pages.each(function(){
        $(this).css("z-index",pages.length-pages.index($(this)))
    })
    pages_flipped.each(function(){
        $(this).css("z-index",pages_flipped.index($(this))+1)
    })    
})
```

As for your update, correct code is:

```
$('.page').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('no-anim').toggleClass('flipped');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If not you are adding a handler that executes before page click and it stops click event propagation

Comment: I just posted the added snippet to show I was toggling `.flipped` class via jquery. But thanks for the correction! Also, the z-index order not updating when the class was toggled is my problem.

Comment: Well, @jklm313 I don't see a reordering of z-index on event click in yoru code. However, I have tried it and seems that even with z-index, the div clicked is different than the correct one

Comment: The fiddle i posted has only my code, you have to add yours in the js panel for the z-index to be added in the descending order. And afterwards wehn you toggle the .flipped class by clicking the next-page button, you'll see the z-index order doesn't get updated, you can see it if you open the inspector and click the next-page button. I hope I was able to be clear.

Comment: @jklm313 Oh had never seen that next-page button, that explains why it wasn't working when I tried. Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/HwR9c/8/

Comment: thank you! this works perfectly! let me do a couple more tests! :)

Answer (score 2):

To assign to the non-flipped elements, in order, this should do the trick:

```
var max = $('div.book div.page:not(.flipped)').length;
$('div.book div.page:not(.flipped)').each(
    function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', max--);
    }
);
```

Then, to assign to the flipped elements:

```
var count = 0;
$('div.book div.flipped').each(
    function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', ++count);
    }
);
```

Since you have multiple book elements on a page, then you would construct it somewhat differently:

```
$('div.book').each(
    function() {
        var max = $(this).children('div.page:not(.flipped)').size();
        $(this).children('div.page:not(.flipped)').each(
            function() {
                $(this).css('z-index', max--);
            }
        );

        var count = 0;
        $(this).children('div.flipped').each(
            function() {
                 $(this).css('z-index', ++count);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

To cause this to get reassigned when you click on the book, then put the above code into a function, and call that function in your book click event, like so:

```
// Slightly modified to work properly, and calls the index function
$('.page').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('no-anim').toggleClass('flipped');
    e.stopPropagation();
    indexPages();
});

// Putting zindex assignment into a function for reuse
function indexPages() {
  $('div.book').each(
        function() {
            var max = $(this).children('div.page:not(.flipped)').size();
            $(this).children('div.page:not(.flipped)').each(
                function() {
                    $(this).css('z-index', max--);
                }
            );

            var count = 0;
            $(this).children('div.flipped').each(
                function() {
                     $(this).css('z-index', ++count);
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Mind if I wait a few before accepting? :)

Answer (score 1):

here you go

keep in mind, that i starts with 0, so if you want to raise it, you have to do it like

```
zIndex: i + 1
```

here is the jquery

```
$(function() {
$(".book").each(function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).is(".flipped")) {
            $(this).css({
                zIndex: i
            });
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                zIndex: $(this).parent().find("div").length - i
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/L8E8a/1/

Comment: The third flipped `.page` is overlapped by the fourth page tho.

Comment: its because i starts with 0, and length starts with 1, (not really, but i counts up from 0 to 4, while length makes 5).. http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/L8E8a/2/

Answer (score 0):

looking for fewer lines?

```
$(".book").each(function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(i) {
        var level = $(this).is(".flipped") ? i : ($(this).parent().find("div").length - 1) - i;
        $(this).css("zIndex", level);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/L8E8a/3/

**EDIT**

hold on a second:

```
$(".book").each(function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(i) {
        $(this).css("zIndex", $(this).is(".flipped") ? (i + 1) : $(this).parent().find("div").length - i);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/L8E8a/5/

:)

Comment: Works fine! Let me just fiddle around with it before making my decision!